How to remove multi-origin composition
The payload data getting passed to OData from Fiori application is with SAP__Origin field that is getting automatically added in the URI parameters list due to multi origin composition done before.
Currently, NetWeaver gateway system is connected to only one backend system. Therefore, the batch call is getting failed as there is no SAP__Origin field available in the OData entity set properties.
Please let me know how to remove the multi-origin composition from the backend.
I tried to check if there are multiple system aliases added to the service in order to make it multi-origin, but there is only one system alias added. I expect the request from the app to succeed which can only happen if multi-origin composition is removed.
Multi origin:

System alias:


This sounds more like a bug or an XY problem. Reach out to SAP support, and describe the issue and what you're actually trying to achieve there.

@BoghyonHoffmann This is a custom application, so SAP will not support for it.

SAP support doesn't exclude custom applications as long as documented best practices have been followed. See 83020 - What is Support – What is Consulting: On Premise Solutions. Please create a new ticket.

@BoghyonHoffmann Sure will raise a ticket to SAP. Thanks.

if this is a custom app then simply remove the ;mo from the service URL in your manifest.json?

Thanks @Marc for your input. The issue is resolved after removing ;mo from manifest.json file.

The issue is resolved by removing ;mo from manifest.json file along with removing the multi-origin parameter(sap__origin) from the batch call statement.
Thank you all for your support and time.
